# Bottom left corner tooltip

Tags: angular, vis.js

It is written in the visjs doc that it is enough to add a title to the different nodes or edges so that a popup is displayed when you hover with the cursor.
I followed the sample code on this link : https://codepen.io/pen/ but is does not work for me.
When I look at my graph in my browser, I see that the vis-tooltip class div is placed at the bottom left of my graph and the popup is not displayed.

When I set manually "position: absolute" in style the popup is displayed well above my cursor:

[image: 1]

I don't understand how to fix the problem since nothing seems to be needed in the sample code and I haven't found other people who have encountered this problem. If anyone can enlighten me on this I would be very grateful.

This is the way I create my nodes :

```
this.nodes.add( {
    id: i,
    label: this.pbn.sites[i].domainName,
    title: "I have a popup!"
  })
```

---

Update :

Normal:

[image: 2]

Manually add position: absolute

[image: 3]

Comment: The codepen link is incorrect, there is no code there.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, or what went wrong.  From you image it looks like you set 'top: 0' in the style, which aligns the top of the element with absolute positioning with the top of the parent that has relative positioning.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Sorry ! it s the "Interaction events" example from https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/   . On the screen i just wanted to show the "position: absolute" but but the position of the popup (top ...) seems to work and changes well depending on the cursor.

Comment: Need more code to really analyze.  But if it's appearing "well above my cursor", but the location changes with your cursor, that leads me to believe that you are setting the position based on the mouse position and that the position is relative to some parent element instead of your graph.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat yes sorry it s hard to post my entire code because i am working on an entire app. I just added two pictures to help the understanding of my problem

Comment: Sorry, that just isn't enough to go off of.  I still don't know if you think the popup *should* appear above your cursor or above a node for instance. If the latter, it looks like it appears above the selected node (lighter color).

Comment: @JasonGoemaat for me the popup should appear like on the second screen : above the selected node, but it work only if i manually set position : absolute in the style

Comment: The way I did my import apparently didn't import the css for the network's popup, if that might help anyone in the future.